# Specifying the font that grub uses for its messages

Tags: grub2, fonts

When Grub boots up, its messages are appearing in a tiny font.  How can I enlarge that font?

Comment: Can you update your question with contents of the grub config file?

Comment: See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup). You can edit `/etc/default/grub` and then run `sudo update-grub`: 1. quick fix: uncomment `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`; 2. fine tuning: use `GRUB_GFXMODE=...`

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to increase the grub font size.

**1)Simple:**

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

Now inside the grub config look for

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE = something
```

You could remove the leading hash and enter a valid screen resolution (such as 600x800, depending on your monitor).

The main disadvantage is that your terminal will stay in that font, e.g. all information on tty will keep this size,

**2) Look for a grub theme that suites you.**

Some of the themes will have extra large fonts or icons.
You'll need to tell grub to use that theme:
GRUB_THEME="/usr/share/path/to/theme"

**3) Create some fonts yourself.**

grub-mkfont is a tool that enables you to [make your own fonts](https://vietlq.github.io/2019/09/22/make-grub-font-size-bigger). This is a little tedious, since you have to check if you like the the fonts during grub start.

Enter in the grub config:

```
GRUB_FONT="/boot/path/to/fonts"
```

Whenever you change sth in grub do not forget do issue

`sudo update-grub`

then reboot